# How to add overlays and then export a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a photo editing app that Im currently moving to swift and would like to expand to allow overlays. At present a UIImageView holds the original image and presents on screen, the image is passed through GPUImage to add filters etc.

I would like for the user to add text/images as overlays and then be allowed to move and resize those overlays (like a lot of current photo editing and drawing apps do). I am currently adding them as subviews of the UIImageView and the resizing/moving is not a problem.

Now the question is how do I go about "transferring" those new subviews onto the original image. I was looking at rendering in context but that only creates an image of the same size as the UIImageView dimension. I am looking to add these overlays to the original image thus keeping the original size of the image.

Any advice on the approach would be great thanks.